# How To Edit Router Web Interface

Tags: router

I am using TalkTalk Huawei HG635.

I was wondering is there any way to edit web interface to add hidden link to navigation.

I want to access html files to add button to access hidden links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible, but most likely not as simple as you would believe it to be.

You would have to go to the trouble of de-compiling and modifying the firmware on the router and then re-flashing it. This is because the html files are embedded in the code you can't just FTP into the router as you would to a server. (You may be able to find the de-compiled code online)

Simpler approaches would be to find custom open-source firmware that is compatible and modify the html pages as needed. This may difficult considering the firmware is more hardware specific and may not work with your specific model.

Other options I can think of are injecting the custom HTML/CSS through a custom browser extension. This is most likely the easiest solution but will only work on the specific browser/computer its installed on.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I can't help feeling it is primarily outside the scope of SO